# Spark select columns on dataframe using a Map with key -> column name

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on Apache spark 2.3.0 cloudera4 and I have an issue selecting a specific column depending on the value in a map.

I have these inputs, a dataframe:

```
+---+---+---+...+
| id| c1| c2| cN|
+---+---+---+...+
|  a|1.0|2.0|...|
|  a|3.0|4.0|...|
|  b|5.0|6.0|...|
|  c|7.0|8.0|...|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Every "c" column is a double type.

And a map:

```
Map("a" -> "c1", "b" -> "c2", "c" -> "c1")
```

I need this output:

```
+---+---+
| id|  c|
+---+---+
|  a|1.0|
|  a|3.0|
|  b|6.0|
|  c|7.0|
+---+---+
```

Which is the best way, from a performance perspective, to get the output?

Now I'm iterating over the map key, selecting the value col and id column with a where clause and doing an union with the previous step (first step is made using an empty dataframe). I think this kind of operations are penalizing my process performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need to use `union` here, iterating over the map variable together with `coalesce` should be enough. This will select the correct column depending on the value in the `id` column and the dictionary:

```scala
import spark.implicits._

val m = Map("a" -> "c1", "b" -> "c2", "c" -> "c1")
val c = coalesce(m.map{case (k,v) => when($"id" === k, col(v)).otherwise(lit(null))}.toSeq: _*)

df.select($"id", c)
```

Comment: Awesome! it takes an 50% less time in process

Comment: @la.leiva: Happy to help :)